# split quadri audio file into 4 monos

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a quadri audio file (one stream of 4tracks) and I would like to make 4 monos track from that stream/

```
ffmpeg -i TRACK-026.wav -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=4[Perche][MixHf][hf1][hf2]" -map "[Perche]" perche.wav -map "[MixHF]" MixHF.wav -map "[hf1]" hf1.wav -map "[hf2]" hf2.wav
```

here's the full log:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : 4.0
Input #0, wav, from 'TRACK-026.wav':
  Metadata:
comment         : sSPEED=030.000-ND
                : sTAKE=026
                : sUBITS=$00000000
                : sSWVER=2.10.71
                : sSCENE=Track
                : sFILENAME=TRACK-026.WAV
                : sTAPE=190822
                : sCIRCLED=FALSE
                : sTRK1=Perche
                : sTRK2=MixHF
                : sTRK4=hf1
                : sTRK5=hf2
                : sNOTE=
                :
encoded_by      : SoundDev: MixPre-10T QD031734201
originator_reference: USSDVQD0317342017190822DQR000101
date            : 2019-08-22
creation_time   : 13:26:54
time_reference  : 0
coding_history  : A=PCM,F=48000,W=24,M=multi,R=48000,T=4 Ch
                :
Duration: 00:32:19.35, bitrate: 4608 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 4.0, s32 (24 bit), 4608 kb/s
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002293f28d500] No output pad can be associated to link label 'MixHf'.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

- `channel_layout=4` to `channel_layout=4.0`. Use layout values from `ffmpeg -layouts`.
- `[MixHf]` to `[MixHF]`

New command:

```
ffmpeg -i TRACK-026.wav -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=4.0[Perche][MixHF][hf1][hf2]" -map "[Perche]" perche.wav -map "[MixHF]" MixHF.wav -map "[hf1]" hf1.wav -map "[hf2]" hf2.wav
```